# How can I update running total of money owed month on month automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet of a monthly coffee fund that all my staff pay in to.

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/24wgjyf/8]

Is it possible in Excel to have a running total of what everybody owes that increases month on month automatically?

And decreases when someone makes a payment?

In the picture above, 'Chris' has a monthly subscription of $10. He owes $10 every month, but sometimes he is late with his payment. Is it possible so when it comes to the 1st of the month, his TOTAL OUTSTANDING (C2) adds $10, unless a figure is put in to the relevant month?

Comment: OT: might want to consider activating that product ;)

Comment: To clarify: You want `TOTAL OUTSTANDING` to be [`SUBSCRIPTION` * (number of months between Jan and now) - (sum of values in columns between Jan and now)]. Is that correct? (Hint: That might help you find the answer, too. `MONTH(TODAY())` returns the number of today's month (`1` - `12`) and functions like `OFFSET` can use that to sum a dynamic range.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in C2, then fill it down:
`=B2* MONTH(TODAY())-SUM(D2:O2)`
Where:

- `MONTH(TODAY())` is the number of actual month (1-12), multiplying it by the monthly subscription gives the payable until actual date
- `SUM(D2:O2)` calculates the total of all the payments done during the year (actually it calculates future month too, but I think it's correct, if somebody pays more and you put in future month you'll see from the calculation that he's overpaying).

Comment: Although your may have answered the question, to make your answer awesome you should explain how it answers the question, how it works and possibly some reference to back it up.